# For what is the @ param within a storename?

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I recently digged into the sourcecode (because of my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699045/customize-the-loader-for-a-mvc-app)) and stumpled over the following line

```
storeId = (name.indexOf("@") == -1) ? name : name.split("@")[0]
```

within the application-controller getStore() method (ExtJS version 4.1.3).

Now I wonder for what is the **@** whitin the storename? I never seen that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in `Ext.app.Controller` uses the '@' to create unambiguous class names, where it's obvious which part is the class name and which part is the namespace. The format is supposed to look something like `Model@Name.space` according to the source.

The method of getting the `storeId` that you posted just means that if there's a '@' then get the class name (the part before the '@') and if there's not, then take the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't see the sense here. `MyApp.store.User` against `User@MyApp.store` ? I wonder if I missed some huge change here?

Comment: I'm not sure why they chose to do it this way. It only does this for stores, and I can't find anything regarding stores in the source where this is utilized. Might be some new feature that has yet to be fully implemented.

Comment: That's interesting. That might be coming up with 4.2

Comment: Thanks for the additional reply

Comment: @sra Confirmed, just saw the release notes for 4.2 beta. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?251214